# Refresh images on a given interval with picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I need a function for my android app to auto refresh images every minute for cctv images. I'm using Picasso for the images and on there website i cant find the solution.

This is the app[image]

On my Activity2.java:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    {
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        String url = "http://www.trakyagumruk.gov.tr/canli_trakya_gtb/kapikule/kapikule_images/kapikule_kamera1/1.jpg";
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);

    }
    {
        ImageView imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
        String url = "http://trakyagumruk.gov.tr/canli_trakya_gtb/kapikule/kapikule_images/kapikule_kamera6/1.jpg";
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView1);
    }

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `TimerTask` would be a good start, and don't use `{}` blocks for loading images

Comment: When i delete the blocks i get Variable 'url' is already defined in the scope.

Comment: Yes, because you're declaring it twice... You can simply rename the second url variable

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler`:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // download your images here
        handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
    }
}, 60000); // 1 minute in ms
```

EDIT:
also, add this line to both Picasso loaders:

```
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
```

It will make sure to load images without storing them in cache

Comment: This only delays the images and does not reload/refresh them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to update the imageView with new images every minute (i.e 60,000ms)

```
        int refreshIntervalMs = 60*1000; //milliseconds
        final Handler handler = new Handler(); // make sure to do this on main thread.
        String url = "http://www.trakyagumruk.gov.tr/canli_trakya_gtb/kapikule/kapikule_images/kapikule_kamera1/1.jpg";
        Runnable imageUpdater = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(this).cancelRequest(imageView); //cancel any pending/ongoing requests
                Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(url)
                        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                        .into(imageView);
                handler.postDelayed(this, refreshIntervalMs);
            }
        };
```

Use the following to start/resume continuously updating the imageView.

```
        handler.post(imageUpdater);
```

Use the following to stop updating.

```
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```